# Retrieving map data from Google or Apple APIs / offline map options?

Tags: ios, google-maps-api-3, mkmapview

I am downloading address information in JSON format and placing annotation pins on a MKMapView.

The data does not contain GPS coordinates and some of the users of the data service enter place names rather than street addresses. I am currently experimenting with Google's maps.googleapis.com to retrieve the GPS coordinates; however this is very slow and I suspect I will quickly exceed the limits Google places on number of daily hits to the service.

I thought about downloading all of the map data to a server, storing the GPS coordinates on that server and having iPhone App query that server. I could also create a CoreData DB with the addresses; however this would not be updated as new addresses are added to web service.

Does anyone have suggestions for other approaches or suggestions for speeding up the original query?

I can post code if that would be helpful.

Thanks!

Comment: thats illegal btw. you aren't allowed to use the geocoder from google without a google map (last I checked)

Comment: Google has API's specific to iPhone, so do not think I am violating any licensing agreements.

Comment: "(g) No Use of Content without a Google Map. ..." - e.g. at https://developers.google.com/maps/terms

Comment: Well, you may be correct, though the paragraph you cited also has the caveat "unless you are explicitly permitted to do so in the Maps APIs Documentation". 

But as I inferred in my question, I am open to other options.

Comment: a) dont cache it on the server, b) use a GMSMapiew OR c) use the apple geocoder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kudos to Daij-Djan. He was correct. With the change to version 5, one can no longer use Google API's without Google maps. There are a lot of tutorials out there demonstrating how to combine iPhone Map with Google API, but presumably this could cause you headaches in the future.

The CLGeocoder works well and is actually faster for the user than the Google API. Here is what I did:

```
- (void) getCoordinatesForTheseLocations:(NSArray*) meetRecords
{
NSInteger countOfAnnotations = [meetRecords count];

if (debug==1) NSLog(@"countOfAnnotations equals %ld", (long)countOfAnnotations);
NSInteger __block iCount = 0;
for (NSDictionary* meet in meetRecords) {

        NSString *location = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@, %@, %@",
                              [[meet objectForKey:MEET_VENUE] stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]],
                              [[meet objectForKey:MEET_CITY] stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]],
                              [[meet objectForKey:MEET_STATE_ABBREV] stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]]];

        CLGeocoder *geocoder = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init];
        [geocoder geocodeAddressString:location completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error) {
            CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinates;
            CLPlacemark* bestGuess;

            if (error)
            {…} else if (placemarks && placemarks.count > 0) {

               NSMutableDictionary* meetInfoForAnnotation = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

                if (debug==2) NSLog(@"meet = %@", meet);

                meetInfoForAnnotation = [meet mutableCopy];

                if (debug==2) NSLog(@"Received placemarks: %@", placemarks);


                bestGuess = [placemarks objectAtIndex:0];
                coordinates.latitude = bestGuess.location.coordinate.latitude;
                coordinates.longitude = bestGuess.location.coordinate.longitude;

                [meetInfoForAnnotation setObject:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:coordinates.longitude] forKey:MEET_LONGITUDE];
                [meetInfoForAnnotation setObject:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:coordinates.latitude] forKey:MEET_LATITUDE];

                [self mapAnnotations:meetInfoForAnnotation];

            }

            if (iCount == countOfAnnotations - 1) {  // Update MapView if have reached end of XML records.
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

                    //            NSLog(@"%@",meetsWithCoordinates);
                    myPinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorPurple;

                    [self setAnnotations:self.meetAnnotations];
                });
            }
            if (debug==1) NSLog(@"iCount = %d and countOfAnnotations = %d",iCount, countOfAnnotations);
            iCount ++;
        }];
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.